# How to access variable from another controller in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I've two controllers in Angular and have a variable in both. 
AddController -->To save/update
Controller 2 --> Get single record based on Id

script :

```
app.controller('AddController', function ($scope, MyService) {

$scope.IsNewRecord = 1; //The flag for the new record
 $scope.Save = function () {
   //Load values in local variable
    };

    //If the flag is 1 then it is new record
    if ($scope.IsNewRecord === 1) {
       //Add new data
        },
    }
    else { 
      //Else Edit the record
    }
```

SingleController : Fetch me single record

```
app.controller('SingleController', function ($scope, MyService) {
$scope.search = function (Id) {
    var promiseGetSingle = MyService.getbyId(Id);

    promiseGetSingle.then(function (pl) {
        var res = pl.data;
       //I ll be using res value in UI to display in text boxes.

           $scope.IsNewRecord = 0; //If i try to edit and save it back, then 
          //in If-Cluse of above controller should be updated with             /               //IsNewRecord value as 0..
    },
```

How to achieve it...how to communicate with another controller to pass my flag value to edit.

If i'm not clear please let me know..i ll ellobrte

Comment: Can you be more accurate on your controllers roles ? How many page do you have ? I think (if I understand well what you are doing here) one of your controller could be replaced by a service, and so your controller wouldn't need to communicate.

Comment: try to extend your controller

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$rootScope` and events to communicate between your controllers. Check [Scope the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) for `$on`, `$broadcast` and `$emit` methods.

```
//On first controller
$rootScope.$broadcast('myEventName', {foo: 'bar'});

//On second controller
$rootScope.$on('myEventName', function (params) {
    params.foo; //bar
});
```

Comment: shouldn't the $broadCast() should be $broadcast()?

Comment: for whoever going to follow this example, bare in mind, in second controller(or any other controller) do not use $rootScope.$on() which is your application. Use $scope.$on() instead. Why? because if your second controller is destroyed the event listener will still exist, next time the controller created again it will just pile up the events.

Comment: you missed 'event' in your, `$rootScope.$on('myEventName', function (params){ params.foo; });`. Should be `$rootScope.$on('myEventName', function (event, params){ params.foo; });`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a service to pass the value using getters and setters.

```
app.service('FlagHandlerService', function() {
    this.setFlagValue = function(flagValue){
         this.flagValue = flagValue;
    }
    this.getFlagValue = function(){
         return this.flagValue;
    }
});
```

Then you can set the value whenever it changes and get it whenever it is needed.
I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: It should. You can inject the service into as many controllers as you like. You can then use the service's getter and setter methods from inside the controller.